# No subset of RE captures the set of TMs halting on themselves as input

Tags: computability, turing-machines

For a property $P$ of languages, which we identify with the set of languages satisfying it, let $L_P = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in P \}$ be the set of descriptions of Turing machines whose languages satisfy $P$.

> How can we prove that there's no property $\displaystyle P\subseteq RE $ for which $ L_{P}=K $, where $K=\{\langle M \rangle \mid M(\langle M \rangle)\!\downarrow\} $?

Comment: Then, can you write down a property $ P $ for $ L_P=K $ ?

Comment: I know that K is recursively enumerable, but that's not the question ( don't care about the title, it changed it's self , I don't know what happened) . The question is if there is property P such that $ L_P=K $ .You must definately know what a propery is in order to find an answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: A language $ P $ of TM descriptions is called property iff: 1) is non-trivial and 2) for every TMs $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $ L(M_1)=L(M_2) $ , then $ <M_1>\in P $ if and only if $<M_2>\in P $

Comment: $L_P=\{ <M> | L(M)\in P\} $

Comment: These definitions are well known in advanced computation theory. If you lack knowledge, it would be better not to answer.

Comment: Please open the book 'Introduction to the theory of computation' of M. Sipser in page 213 and look at exercise 5.28 (the book exists online also).

Comment: I copied the definitions in Sipser's book. If you don't agree, you could ask him yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the recursion theorem, there is a Turing machine $M$ such that $L(M) = \{\langle M \rangle\}$. If $P$ is a property such that $L_P = K$ then $\langle M \rangle \in K$ implies that $L(M) = \{ \langle M \rangle \} \in P$. Now it is easy to construct a different machine $M' \neq M$ such that $L(M') = \{ \langle M \rangle \}$. Since $L(M') \in P$ and $L_P = K$, we must have $\langle M' \rangle \in K$, yet $M'$ doesn't halt on $\langle M' \rangle$.

Note that this solution doesn't use the condition $P \subseteq RE$.